# How can i edit my asp.net mvc3 web application that is published on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, deployment, asp.net-mvc

I published an ASP.NET MVC3 web application three months ago on ISS 7.5 using the web deployment package from the Visual Studio.  While deploying I chose **Only files needed to run this application**.

Now I need to edit the web application to add some new features.  I need to edit/add views, controllers and also update the database.

**How can I work on the web deployment package within IIS 7.5 that is installed on the client server?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't have access to the models/controllers as those will be copiled into the .dll. You will need to have the original source to make changes to those files.

oh and P.S. If you don't have the source anymore it is possible to retrieve it from the dll with a decompiler e.g. here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I already saved a copy of the whole project prior to deploy it in the customer side. But my concern if i apply my chnages to the copy which i have and i re-deploy the application on the IIS 7.5 ,, then how can i keep the live data avilable in the new release ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with "live data" if you are only deploying new application files it shouldn't affect the database ?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my case i also need to add some tables and modify exsisting tables (by adding new columns to them) in addtion to modifying the application files.